# How, in Silverlight, can one keep the contents of a user control completely private?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I'm creating a user control to contain credit card information provided by the user. The control collects account number, expiration, and CCV.

I want the only output from this control to be a single property representing an encrypted string.

I already have this property, and I've made my control's private and set up binding in a way that it doesn't use public properties.  All that is working.  I just want to somehow disable visual tree searching and the `FindName` method from being able to excise the credit card information from the control.

I am aware that this seems overzealous, but can is there even a way to do this?

Comment: FindName is not going to allow access to the private properties, so you should be all set.

Comment: It does allow access to private _controls_ from what I've experienced.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not storing the information in a control. How about processing it from BackgroundWorker or something else that isn't seen by the VisualTree? Then communicate back to the control using the encrypted string only.

Comment: Its a point of user entry.  I am instantly encrypting the credit card information and posting it to the server for processing.  But it has to be exposed to the user, just not to other controls and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at how it's done in the templated SL BussinessApplication where a Func is used?

```
public string Password
{
    get
    {
        return (this.PasswordAccessor == null) ? string.Empty : this.PasswordAccessor();
    }
    set
    {
        this.ValidateProperty("Password", value);

        // Do not store the password in a private field as it should not be stored in memory in plain-text.
        // Instead, the supplied PasswordAccessor serves as the backing store for the value.

        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a function that returns the password.
/// </summary>
internal Func<string> PasswordAccessor { get; set; }
```

Comment: Its not my property that I'm worried about.  I'm internally binding it to a private view model.  My concern is with `TextBox.Text`.  I know it's overkill, but I'm zealous about protecting user data, and good enough if not always good enough.

Comment: Is it encrypted when stored in the ViewModel?  If not, it's in memory in plain text, on the client machine.  It doesn't matter if the VM is private or not.

Comment: So I need a custom text box that directly encrypts the number as the user enters it.  I'm really wanting this to be secure from beginning to end.  Maybe it is overkill.  I don't know.